# Play Video and Audio simultaneously on HTML5 page

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I'm currently having a problem where i need to be able to test user devices(camera and audio) on the same page. For the camera i use `getUserMedia` and then display it inside a  tag on a page like so:

```
this.refs.myVideoRef.srcObject  = mystream
```

I also have an audio object that plays my test audio file without issues until I assign a stream to the video(like above)

```
<audio controls ref='audioTest' src="myTest.mp3" />
```

Once video starts playing audio is muted and cannot be reset. Even if i manually set `muted` property for both objects as expected I still cannot hear the `<audio />` anymore.

Is there a way to set somehow that `<audio />` always overrides the `<video />`? or is there a better way to do it?